# Select from either of two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables.

Lets call them `Table1` and `Table2`. Both tables have the same structure and data type.

`Table1` is a transaction table and `Table2` is a historical data table.

I need to do something like this:

```
Select * from case  when 'transnational' then Table1 else Table2 end
```

I do not want to use 2 `select` statement to do this however.

Can I use the `CASE` statement for this?

Comment: there is no way of doing that. You can create a view union both table and then query that view

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL`: `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE @param = 'transnational' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE @param <> 'transnational' `

Comment: Just to have mentioned it: You might think about dynamic SQL too, but you cannot use this within ad-hoc approaches like VIEWs or JOINs. My approach was the `UNION ALL` with filter...

Answer (score 2):

Great question! Let's try:

```
Create Table tab0 (col int primary key);
Create Table tab1 (col int primary key);

Insert Into tab0 (col) Values (0);
Insert Into tab1 (col) Values (1);
GO
```

Minimalist Union All solution would be:

```
Declare @tabindex bit = 0;
Select * From tab0 Where @tabindex = 1 Union All
Select * From tab1 Where @tabindex = 0;
```

Execution plan indicate two table scans and filters with one concatenation.

That is not good enough. Let's see whether optimizer can actually skip table processing if conditions are not right:

```
Select * From tab0 Where 1 = 1 Union All
Select * From tab1 Where 1 = 0
GO
```

... and Execution plan indicate **one** table scan and one Compute Scalar at cost 0%. So, technically optimizer **can** do it. The problem is any condition involving variable would get evaluated against the table resulting in a table scan. So we just need to evaluate the condition before `Select`. Well, there is an answer to that too by the name of **table-valued function**:

```
Create Function tab (@tabNo int)
Returns @RetTab Table (col int)
As
Begin
  If @tabNo = 1 Insert Into @RetTab Select * From tab1
  Else          Insert Into @RetTab Select * From tab0;
  Return;
End;
```

Now if we run `Select * From tab(1);` or `Select * From tab(0);` Execution plan would indicate just one table scan, one Table Valued Function and one Sequence both costing 0%.

So the answer is **yes, we can use `CASE` statement in table-valued function**.

**Update** following [Shnugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089204/shnugo) comment. The function can actually be improved:

```
Create Function tab (@tabNo int)
Returns Table
As
  Return
    Select * From tab0 Where @tabNo = 0 Union All
    Select * From tab1 Where @tabNo = 1;
GO
```

Now `Select * From tab(1);` or `Select * From tab(0);` results in one Table Scan and one Compute Scalar only. Apparently with compiled function the optimizer know not to look for the parameter variable in the table.

Comment: This would need further tests... The TVF with BEGIN and END is well known for its awful performance. Better than dynamic Sql (useable with ad-hoc) but in most real world scenarios probably not as fast as the UNION ALL. Anyway worth an upvote

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for the hint!