# SQL case for selecting table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have to query from a table or a view on two condition. I could repeat it with if conditions, but in my scenario it need to be in one query,

Something like a procedure that is receiving a flag `@reportType int`

```
SELECT 
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h,... and so many 
FROM 
    CASE 
       WHEN @reportType = 1 
          THEN table 
          ELSE View 
    END
INNER JOIN 
    and so on..
```

I need to write like above  but it is throwing an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

Comment: AFAIK, case expression returns a value, not an identifier. it can't be done like this, only by using either dynamic sql or an if...else condition.

Comment: I've edit your question that you can roll all back ;).

Comment: Same as: [Select from either of two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36857438/select-from-either-of-two-tables/36860365)

Answer (score 1):

In your stored procedure, you need to use an if statement instead:

```
if @reportType=1
    SELECT a,b,c FROM myTable
else
    SELECT a,b,c FROM myView
```

Comment: Yes, but in my case SELECT a,b,c will be same but myTable and myView will be conditional and the query is too long to be spited.

Comment: Then I can only think of two options. 1) Do it with dynamic SQL (assign the query text to a `varchar` and execute it). Or 2) Create a view with the content of both tables and add a condition in the `where` that filters the corresponding table.

Comment: I think i should go for IF else condition because The two way will be time consuming Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually this does not look like a good design, but if you have to work with this and wish to avoid copy-past, you may try conditional CTEs with final union or one subquery with union to imitate single source for final query:

```
;with Source_1 as
(
  select ...
  from myTable
  where @reportType=1
),
Source_2 as
(
  select ...
  from myView
  where @reportType=2
),
FullSource
(
   select ...
   from Source_1
   union all
   select ...
   from Source_2
)
select ...
from FullSource src
inner join ...
```

or

```
select ...
from 
(
  select ...
  from myTable
  where @reportType = 1

  union all

  select ...
  from myView
  where @reportType = 2
) src
inner join ...
```

Note, different possible flows confuse query optimizer and this code is not good for performance. For some better execution plan you will probably need to enable `recompile` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL as below:

```
DECLARE @reportType INT
SET @reportType = 1

DECLARE @q VARCHAR(max)= 'SELECT 
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h,... and so many 
FROM '+
CASE 
   WHEN @reportType = 1 
      THEN 'table '
      ELSE 'View '
END+'
INNER JOIN 
and so on..'

EXEC(@q)
```

You may also want to use sp_executesql in order to make the query parametric and prevent the possible SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a query like this:

```
;WITH mixedData AS (
    SELECT yourFields, 1 As reportType 
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yourFields, 2 AS reportType
    FROM yourView
)
SELECT *
FROM mixedData 
INNER JOIN yourJoinParams
WHERE mixedData.reportType = @reportType;
```

or

```
...
WHERE mixedData.reportType = 
      CASE WHEN @reportType = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

Note that `yourFields` from `yourTable` and `yourView` are same.

HTH